# How can I capture screenshot of a screen with a popup in xamarin in iPhone?

Tags: ios, xamarin, popup, screenshot

I need to capture the screen of my App in iPhone. Whenever there is a pop up page to be captured, only the pop up view is visible in the screenshot, the background screen goes black in the screenshot captured. I need the screenshot to show the pop up along with the underlying page.

I am coding in `Xamarin.Forms`. I am using DependencyService to capture screenshot in iOS and Android.

In Android I am able to capture popup along with background page.
But in iOS the popup along with a black background is captured.

`var capture = UIScreen.MainScreen.Capture();`

This is the code in iOS DependencyService to capture screenshot.

Comment: This must be happening because you are capturing the screenshot with the popup on it which makes the pop-up the MainScreen and hence only that is captured!!

Comment: @G.hakim  I understand that the pop-up is becoming the 'MainScreen' when trying to capture screenshot with popup on the screen. What must be the code change I need to do to capture the entire screen with the pop up on it?

Comment: Did this work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I had a screenshot method that I used in one of my POC's but I am not sure if it will work with the pop-up thing or not you can try it out

```
 private void TakeScreenshot()
    {
        var layer = UIApplication.SharedApplication?.KeyWindow?.Layer;
        var scale = UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale;
        UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.Frame.Size, false, scale);
        var context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
        if (context == null)
        {
            return; // Show popup screenshot was not taken 
        }
        layer.RenderInContext(context);
        var screenshotImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
        if (screenshotImage != null)
        {
            screenshotImage.SaveToPhotosAlbum((UIImage, NSError) => { });
        }

    }
```